# String Concatenating functions in Progress 4GL?

Tags: string-concatenation, progress-4gl

I came across a function in C#, string.Join() which is really helpful for string concatenation.
I am wondering is there any possibility of doing the same functionality in Progress 4GL ?
Typical C# example would be,

> ```
> String result = “ ”;
>
> result = string.Join(",", this.grpBox1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
>                                     .Where(x => x.Checked)
>                                     .Select(c => c.Text));
> MessageBox.Show(result);
> ```

I am not trying to convert C# to Progress but it would be really helpful if i could achieve the same functionality in Progress.

Comment: What is the result in C#?

Comment: It gives you a comma separated list of all checked checkbox texts inside the grpBox1 control.

Comment: join really comes into its own in languages with enumerated types, and we don't have that.  What we have instead are functions to manipulate a list of strings separated by a delimiter -- entry(), lookup(), etc.. So you could say that the reason we don't have much use for a function that turns an array into a comma-seperated list is: we can manipulate the comma-seperated list in the first place...

Comment: I know Progress is capable of manipulating a comma-separated list and above function is more powerful than them as it can identify only the checked textboxes and concatenate their names from an one line of code.

Answer (score 0):

if you do really want your function you could wrap it and  declare it as external you can  re-link _progres to include your own c libs. used to be called HLC (probuild) but now its a set of scripts under a new directory name oebuild directly under the Progress install directory(DLC). The hlc and make directories are under the oebuild directory.

Instructions on the build process can be found in the README file located in the oebuild directory under the DLC directory.  Prob. a sledge hammer to crack a nut you would have to understand what your doing not for the faint of heart. but if you have something written in c you want to call you can do it.  prob. best to stick to the 4gl nearest thing progress has to arrays is extent not used much most people break out to a temp table . rows in a tt are far easier to handle and iterate so its a "mind set" switch a bit.

Important comments can also be found in the hlprodsp.c file located in the hlc directory, a subdirectory of oebuild.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, there's nothing built in to that effort. But if I understand correctly, when you issue that command you get a list of that given object type (in your example, checkbox) as a CSV.
I built something that resembles it, as a start to whatever you'd like to implement. It's probably far from perfect, but it works for me. It's a window with various widget types, you select from the combo the type you'd like to search and generate, and it will show you at the end the values of two CSV variables: one with the widget names that match that type, and one with the respective values.

Here it goes:

```
&Scoped-define WINDOW-NAME C-Win
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------

  File: 

  Description: 

  Input Parameters:
      <none>

  Output Parameters:
      <none>

  Author: 

  Created: 

------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*          This .W file was created with the Progress AppBuilder.      */
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* Create an unnamed pool to store all the widgets created 
     by this procedure. This is a good default which assures
     that this procedure's triggers and internal procedures 
     will execute in this procedure's storage, and that proper
     cleanup will occur on deletion of the procedure. */

CREATE WIDGET-POOL.

/* ***************************  Definitions  ************************** */

/* Parameters Definitions ---                                           */

/* Local Variable Definitions ---                                       */

DEFINE VARIABLE cWidgetLst AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cValueLst  AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.



/* ********************  Preprocessor Definitions  ******************** */

&Scoped-define PROCEDURE-TYPE Window
&Scoped-define DB-AWARE no

/* Name of designated FRAME-NAME and/or first browse and/or first query */
&Scoped-define FRAME-NAME DEFAULT-FRAME

/* Standard List Definitions                                            */
&Scoped-Define ENABLED-OBJECTS COMBO-BOX-1 BUTTON-1 SLIDER-1 SELECT-1 ~
RADIO-SET-1 TOGGLE-1 FILL-IN-2 COMBO-BOX-3 
&Scoped-Define DISPLAYED-OBJECTS COMBO-BOX-1 SLIDER-1 SELECT-1 RADIO-SET-1 ~
TOGGLE-1 FILL-IN-2 COMBO-BOX-3 

/* Custom List Definitions                                              */
/* List-1,List-2,List-3,List-4,List-5,List-6                            */

/* ***********************  Control Definitions  ********************** */

/* Define the widget handle for the window                              */
DEFINE VAR C-Win AS WIDGET-HANDLE NO-UNDO.

/* Definitions of the field level widgets                               */
DEFINE BUTTON BUTTON-1 
     LABEL "Generate" 
     SIZE 15 BY 1.14.

DEFINE VARIABLE COMBO-BOX-1 AS CHARACTER FORMAT "X(256)":U 
     VIEW-AS COMBO-BOX INNER-LINES 5
     LIST-ITEMS "Fill-in","Radio-set","Toggle-box","Selection-List","slider","combo-box" 
     DROP-DOWN-LIST
     SIZE 16 BY 1 NO-UNDO.

DEFINE VARIABLE COMBO-BOX-3 AS CHARACTER FORMAT "X(256)":U 
     LABEL "Combo 3" 
     VIEW-AS COMBO-BOX INNER-LINES 5
     LIST-ITEMS "Large","Tall","Venti" 
     DROP-DOWN-LIST
     SIZE 16 BY 1 NO-UNDO.

DEFINE VARIABLE FILL-IN-2 AS CHARACTER FORMAT "X(256)":U 
     LABEL "Fill 2" 
     VIEW-AS FILL-IN 
     SIZE 14 BY 1 NO-UNDO.

DEFINE VARIABLE RADIO-SET-1 AS INTEGER 
     VIEW-AS RADIO-SET VERTICAL
     RADIO-BUTTONS 
          "Item 1", 1,
"Item 2", 2,
"Item 3", 3
     SIZE 12 BY 3 NO-UNDO.

DEFINE VARIABLE SELECT-1 AS CHARACTER 
     VIEW-AS SELECTION-LIST SINGLE SCROLLBAR-VERTICAL 
     LIST-ITEMS "First","Second","Third" 
     SIZE 23 BY 2 NO-UNDO.

DEFINE VARIABLE SLIDER-1 AS INTEGER INITIAL 0 
     VIEW-AS SLIDER MIN-VALUE 0 MAX-VALUE 100 HORIZONTAL 
     TIC-MARKS NONE 
     SIZE 31 BY 2.38 NO-UNDO.

DEFINE VARIABLE TOGGLE-1 AS LOGICAL INITIAL no 
     LABEL "Toggle 1" 
     VIEW-AS TOGGLE-BOX
     SIZE 13.4 BY .81 NO-UNDO.

DEFINE VARIABLE COMBO-BOX-2 AS CHARACTER FORMAT "X(256)":U 
     LABEL "Combo 2" 
     VIEW-AS COMBO-BOX INNER-LINES 5
     LIST-ITEMS "Item 1" 
     DROP-DOWN-LIST
     SIZE 16 BY 1 NO-UNDO.

DEFINE VARIABLE FILL-IN-3 AS CHARACTER FORMAT "X(256)":U 
     LABEL "Fill 3" 
     VIEW-AS FILL-IN 
     SIZE 14 BY 1 NO-UNDO.

DEFINE VARIABLE RADIO-SET-2 AS INTEGER 
     VIEW-AS RADIO-SET VERTICAL
     RADIO-BUTTONS 
          "Item 1", 1,
"Item 2", 2,
"Item 3", 3
     SIZE 12 BY 3 NO-UNDO.

DEFINE VARIABLE SLIDER-2 AS INTEGER INITIAL 0 
     VIEW-AS SLIDER MIN-VALUE 0 MAX-VALUE 100 HORIZONTAL 
     TIC-MARKS NONE 
     SIZE 17 BY 2.14 NO-UNDO.

DEFINE VARIABLE TOGGLE-2 AS LOGICAL INITIAL no 
     LABEL "Toggle 2" 
     VIEW-AS TOGGLE-BOX
     SIZE 13.4 BY .81 NO-UNDO.


/* ************************  Frame Definitions  *********************** */

DEFINE FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME
     COMBO-BOX-1 AT ROW 1.95 COL 13 COLON-ALIGNED NO-LABEL WIDGET-ID 14
     BUTTON-1 AT ROW 1.95 COL 32 WIDGET-ID 2
     SLIDER-1 AT ROW 3.62 COL 42 NO-LABEL WIDGET-ID 18
     SELECT-1 AT ROW 3.86 COL 10 NO-LABEL WIDGET-ID 16
     RADIO-SET-1 AT ROW 6.24 COL 10 NO-LABEL WIDGET-ID 6
     TOGGLE-1 AT ROW 6.24 COL 30 WIDGET-ID 10
     FILL-IN-2 AT ROW 7.19 COL 28 COLON-ALIGNED WIDGET-ID 12
     COMBO-BOX-3 AT ROW 7.29 COL 56 COLON-ALIGNED WIDGET-ID 20
    WITH 1 DOWN NO-BOX KEEP-TAB-ORDER OVERLAY 
         SIDE-LABELS NO-UNDERLINE THREE-D 
         AT COL 1 ROW 1
         SIZE 80 BY 16 WIDGET-ID 100.

DEFINE FRAME FRAME-A
     TOGGLE-2 AT ROW 1.24 COL 51 WIDGET-ID 6
     RADIO-SET-2 AT ROW 1.48 COL 3 NO-LABEL WIDGET-ID 2
     FILL-IN-3 AT ROW 1.95 COL 25 COLON-ALIGNED WIDGET-ID 8
     SLIDER-2 AT ROW 3.14 COL 46 NO-LABEL WIDGET-ID 12
     COMBO-BOX-2 AT ROW 3.38 COL 24 COLON-ALIGNED WIDGET-ID 10
    WITH 1 DOWN KEEP-TAB-ORDER OVERLAY 
         SIDE-LABELS NO-UNDERLINE THREE-D 
         AT COL 5 ROW 10.29
         SIZE 72 BY 5.71
         TITLE "Frame A" WIDGET-ID 200.


/* *********************** Procedure Settings ************************ */

/* Settings for THIS-PROCEDURE
   Type: Window
   Allow: Basic,Browse,DB-Fields,Window,Query
   Other Settings: COMPILE
 */

/* *************************  Create Window  ************************** */

IF SESSION:DISPLAY-TYPE = "GUI":U THEN
  CREATE WINDOW C-Win ASSIGN
         HIDDEN             = YES
         TITLE              = "<insert window title>"
         HEIGHT             = 16
         WIDTH              = 80
         MAX-HEIGHT         = 16
         MAX-WIDTH          = 80
         VIRTUAL-HEIGHT     = 16
         VIRTUAL-WIDTH      = 80
         RESIZE             = yes
         SCROLL-BARS        = no
         STATUS-AREA        = no
         BGCOLOR            = ?
         FGCOLOR            = ?
         KEEP-FRAME-Z-ORDER = yes
         THREE-D            = yes
         MESSAGE-AREA       = no
         SENSITIVE          = yes.
ELSE {&WINDOW-NAME} = CURRENT-WINDOW.
/* END WINDOW DEFINITION                                                */



/* ***********  Runtime Attributes and AppBuilder Settings  *********** */

/* SETTINGS FOR WINDOW C-Win
  VISIBLE,,RUN-PERSISTENT                                               */
/* REPARENT FRAME */
ASSIGN FRAME FRAME-A:FRAME = FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME:HANDLE.

/* SETTINGS FOR FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME
   FRAME-NAME                                                           */

DEFINE VARIABLE XXTABVALXX AS LOGICAL NO-UNDO.

ASSIGN XXTABVALXX = FRAME FRAME-A:MOVE-AFTER-TAB-ITEM (COMBO-BOX-3:HANDLE IN FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME)
/* END-ASSIGN-TABS */.

/* SETTINGS FOR FRAME FRAME-A
                                                                        */
IF SESSION:DISPLAY-TYPE = "GUI":U AND VALID-HANDLE(C-Win)
THEN C-Win:HIDDEN = no.






/* ************************  Control Triggers  ************************ */

&Scoped-define SELF-NAME C-Win
ON END-ERROR OF C-Win /* <insert window title> */
OR ENDKEY OF {&WINDOW-NAME} ANYWHERE DO:
  /* This case occurs when the user presses the "Esc" key.
     In a persistently run window, just ignore this.  If we did not, the
     application would exit. */
  IF THIS-PROCEDURE:PERSISTENT THEN RETURN NO-APPLY.
END.


ON WINDOW-CLOSE OF C-Win /* <insert window title> */
DO:
  /* This event will close the window and terminate the procedure.  */
  APPLY "CLOSE":U TO THIS-PROCEDURE.
  RETURN NO-APPLY.
END.


&Scoped-define SELF-NAME BUTTON-1
ON CHOOSE OF BUTTON-1 IN FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME /* Generate */
DO:
  assign cWidgetLst = ''
         cValueLst  = ''.
  run downTheRabbitHole ( input {&window-name}:handle).

MESSAGE cWidgetLst SKIP cValueLst
    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
END.


&UNDEFINE SELF-NAME



/* ***************************  Main Block  *************************** */

/* Set CURRENT-WINDOW: this will parent dialog-boxes and frames.        */
ASSIGN CURRENT-WINDOW                = {&WINDOW-NAME} 
       THIS-PROCEDURE:CURRENT-WINDOW = {&WINDOW-NAME}.

/* The CLOSE event can be used from inside or outside the procedure to  */
/* terminate it.                                                        */
ON CLOSE OF THIS-PROCEDURE 
   RUN disable_UI.

/* Best default for GUI applications is...                              */
PAUSE 0 BEFORE-HIDE.

/* Now enable the interface and wait for the exit condition.            */
/* (NOTE: handle ERROR and END-KEY so cleanup code will always fire.    */
MAIN-BLOCK:
DO ON ERROR   UNDO MAIN-BLOCK, LEAVE MAIN-BLOCK
   ON END-KEY UNDO MAIN-BLOCK, LEAVE MAIN-BLOCK:
  RUN enable_UI.
  IF NOT THIS-PROCEDURE:PERSISTENT THEN
    WAIT-FOR CLOSE OF THIS-PROCEDURE.
END.


/* **********************  Internal Procedures  *********************** */

PROCEDURE buildCSV :
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Purpose:     
  Parameters:  <none>
  Notes:       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
DEFINE INPUT-OUTPUT PARAMETER iopcList AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE INPUT        PARAMETER ipcValue AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.

if ipcValue = ? then
   assign ipcValue = '?'.
if ipcValue = '' then
   assign ipcValue = ' '.
assign iopcList = iopcList + (if iopcList = '' then '' else ',') + ipcValue.
END PROCEDURE.

PROCEDURE disable_UI :
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Purpose:     DISABLE the User Interface
  Parameters:  <none>
  Notes:       Here we clean-up the user-interface by deleting
               dynamic widgets we have created and/or hide 
               frames.  This procedure is usually called when
               we are ready to "clean-up" after running.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
  /* Delete the WINDOW we created */
  IF SESSION:DISPLAY-TYPE = "GUI":U AND VALID-HANDLE(C-Win)
  THEN DELETE WIDGET C-Win.
  IF THIS-PROCEDURE:PERSISTENT THEN DELETE PROCEDURE THIS-PROCEDURE.
END PROCEDURE.

PROCEDURE downTheRabbitHole :
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Purpose:     
  Parameters:  <none>
  Notes:       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
DEFINE INPUT  PARAMETER iphWidget    AS HANDLE      NO-UNDO.

DEFINE VARIABLE hHandle AS HANDLE      NO-UNDO.

assign hHandle = iphWidget:first-child.


do while valid-handle(hHandle):
   if can-query(hHandle,"type") and hHandle:type = combo-box-1:screen-value in frame {&frame-name} then do:
      /* something something something dark side... */
      if can-query(hHandle,"name") then run buildCSV(input-output cWidgetLst,hHandle:name).
      if can-query(hHandle,"screen-value") then run buildCSV(input-output cValueLst,hHandle:screen-value).
   end.
   if hHandle:type = "FIELD-GROUP" or hHandle:type = "FRAME" then
      run downTheRabbitHole(input hHandle:first-child).
   assign hHandle = hHandle:next-sibling.
end.

END PROCEDURE.

PROCEDURE enable_UI :
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Purpose:     ENABLE the User Interface
  Parameters:  <none>
  Notes:       Here we display/view/enable the widgets in the
               user-interface.  In addition, OPEN all queries
               associated with each FRAME and BROWSE.
               These statements here are based on the "Other 
               Settings" section of the widget Property Sheets.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
  DISPLAY COMBO-BOX-1 SLIDER-1 SELECT-1 RADIO-SET-1 TOGGLE-1 FILL-IN-2 
          COMBO-BOX-3 
      WITH FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME IN WINDOW C-Win.
  ENABLE COMBO-BOX-1 BUTTON-1 SLIDER-1 SELECT-1 RADIO-SET-1 TOGGLE-1 FILL-IN-2 
         COMBO-BOX-3 
      WITH FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME IN WINDOW C-Win.
  {&OPEN-BROWSERS-IN-QUERY-DEFAULT-FRAME}
  DISPLAY TOGGLE-2 RADIO-SET-2 FILL-IN-3 SLIDER-2 COMBO-BOX-2 
      WITH FRAME FRAME-A IN WINDOW C-Win.
  ENABLE TOGGLE-2 RADIO-SET-2 FILL-IN-3 SLIDER-2 COMBO-BOX-2 
      WITH FRAME FRAME-A IN WINDOW C-Win.
  {&OPEN-BROWSERS-IN-QUERY-FRAME-A}
  VIEW C-Win.
END PROCEDURE.
```

Comment: I think you should try to minimize the code posted in your answer. This is very difficult too look at. All you really should need is a single PROCEDURE statement... Also: is this really an answer? Hard to tell just by looking at it...

Comment: Hi, Jens,

First, yes, this is an answer. Just post the whole code (it's a proof of concept window, thus the long program) in the appBuilder and run. After understanding what it does, yes, all that's left is look at the trigger and procedure that actually do the function he's asking for.

Comment: @bupereira so why don't you just post those, instead of the whole thing, it looks confusing and hard to get a broad view

Comment: Because OP didn't seem very knowledgeable in the language in the first place, just wanted to make it super-easy for him.